# How do you handle Touch Events in a UITableView

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm trying to apply an event to a cell in order to specify the TouchesBegan method.

```
cell.TouchesBegan += OnTouchesBegan;
```

But TouchesBegan is a method group and not an event.

How do I add custom behavior to a Cells `TouchesBegan()` method in monotouch?

```
[Register("MenuView")]
public class MenuView : ViewControllerBase
{
    private new MenuViewModel ViewModel { get { return (MenuViewModel)base.ViewModel; } }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        // this ensures the sliding panel doesn't fill the entire view.
        var frame = View.Frame;
        frame.Width = 300;
        View.Frame = frame;

        var chapters = ViewModel.Chapters;

        //var listHeight = (chapters.Count*40);
        var navigationList = new UITableView(new RectangleF(0, 50, 300, 300))
            {
                Source = new NavigationTableSource(chapters)
            };
        Add(navigationList);
    }
}

public class NavigationTableSource : UITableViewSource
{
    private readonly IList<ChapterViewModel> _chapters;
    private const string CellIdentifier = "NavigationCell";

    public NavigationTableSource(IList<ChapterViewModel> chapters)
    {
        _chapters = chapters;
    }

    public override int RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, int section)
    {
        return _chapters.Count;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CellIdentifier) ??
                   new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, CellIdentifier);
        // if there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
        cell.TextLabel.Text = _chapters[indexPath.Row].Title;
        cell.TouchesBegan += OnTouchesBegan;
        return cell;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way I was able to manage this was to SubClass my UITableViewSource. In there I overrode `RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)`

```
public class NavigationTableSource : UITableViewSource
{
    private readonly IList<ChapterViewModel> _chapters;
    private const string CellIdentifier = "NavigationCell";

    public NavigationTableSource(IList<ChapterViewModel> chapters)
    {
        _chapters = chapters;
    }

    public override int RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, int section)
    {
        return _chapters.Count;
    }

    public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        // todo: This is where we're going to load up the appropriate chapter.
        new UIAlertView("Row Selected", _chapters[indexPath.Row].Title, null, "OK", null).Show();
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CellIdentifier) ??
                   new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, CellIdentifier);
        // if there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
        cell.TextLabel.Text = _chapters[indexPath.Row].Title;
        return cell;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TouchesBegan is a method that you can override by subclassing UITableViewCell:

```
public class CustomCell : UITableViewCell
{
    public CustomCell(UITableViewCellStyle style, NSString reuseIdentifier) : base(style, reuseIdentifier)
    {
    }

    public override void TouchesBegan(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        // do something

        base.TouchesBegan(touches, evt);
    }
}
```

Then use your subclass when creating a cell:

```
var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CellIdentifier) ??
               new CustomCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, CellIdentifier);
```

Comment: wow, so as I'm discovering in my noobness to iOS is that there aren't really any Event listeners that you can set, and beyond that there aren't really any Properties you can set either. Everything is Method Groups and require full Custom classes for anything you want to do...